# Delete Before Insert in Doctrine flush

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Case entity which can have many Floors (OneToMany), each Floor has a FloorType which specifies its type. I also have a UniqueConstraint on my Floors entity which won't allow two Floors of the same FloorType for each Case.

In order to insert Floors into each Case, I created a Symfony Collection type for Floors and using js I add new Floors to my Case.

Symfony's doc for form collections says that if an item is not submitted, it would automatically be deleted from DB.

Now the problem is that if I have a Floors for a Case already in DB, when I remove the Floor in my form and add it again, it would be considered as a new INSERT, but since Doctrine performs the flush by doing the INSERTs first and DELETEs last, I would get the error below for violating the uniqueConstraint I set:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-2' for key 'floors_case_floor_type_unique'

Meaning that Doctrine is trying to insert a row into Floors table with same FloorType as the removed one, before trying to remove the last one from the same table.

Is there any way to make doctrine do the DELETE before INSERT, or any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be a [FormEvent](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).
I suggest you [register your FormType as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#b-defining-the-form-as-a-service) so you can *inject doctrine*:

```
# in your services.yml:
services:
    yourbundle.form.case_type:
        class: Your\Bundle\CaseType
        arguments: ["@doctrine"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: your_bundle_case_type }
```

And extend your *FormType*:

```
class CaseType /*...*/
{
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct($doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }
}
```

Now register an *EventListener* in your `buildForm` method of your `CaseType`:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
     $data = $event->getData();
     $em  = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager();

     foreach ($data['floor'] as $floor) {
         // delete floors here...
         $duplicateFloor = $em->find('YourBundle:Floor', $floor->getId);
         $em->remove($duplicateFloor);
     }
     $em->flush();
});
```

Comment: I tried to remove the floors by hand, not in an event but in my controller after the form validation. But the problem is that if I do the flush after removing the floors, since the Case is already under Doctrine's watch, it would again try to do the INSERTs before the DELETE.